# Returning a QuerySnapshot from a callable Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to return a `QuerySnapshot` from a callable Google Cloud Function.

Below are the details, but my core question is, should I expect to be able to do this or is this a bug?

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as firestore from '@google-cloud/firestore';

export const callableTest = functions.https.onCall(
    async (data: Map<string, any>, context: functions.https.CallableContext):
        Promise<firestore.QuerySnapshot> => {
        const db = admin.firestore();
        return db.collection('test')
            .get();

        // I also tried this
        //return db.collection('test').get().then(querySnapshot => {
        //    return querySnapshot;
        //});
    });
```

The `test` collection can contain any number of documents.  In this case, there are two documents.

Here is my client HTML page, but I've also tried this in Flutter and Node with the same result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.3/firebase.js"></script>
      <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
          apiKey: "### API KEY ###",
          authDomain: "<project-id>.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com",
          projectId: "<project-id>",
          storageBucket: "<project-id>.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "<sender-id>"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var testClientCall = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('callableTest');
        testClientCall ({}).then(function(result) {
          // Read result of the Cloud Function.
          console.log("Cloud Function result:");
          console.log(result);
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

This is the returned result, which *looks* like a `QuerySnapshot`, but doesn't contain any `DocumentSnapshots` (`_docs` property) even though the `_size` property indicates there should be two documents.

```
{"data":{"_query":{"_firestore":{"_clientPool":{"concurrentOperationLimit":100,"clientFactory":{},"activeClients":{}},"_settings":{"projectId":"<project-id>","firebaseVersion":"6.4.0","libName":"gccl","libVersion":"0.19.0 fire/6.4.0"},"_settingsFrozen":false,"_clientInitialized":{"domain":{"domain":null,"_events":{"error":{}},"_eventsCount":1,"_maxListeners":null,"members":[]}},"_serializer":{"createReference":{},"timestampsInSnapshots":false},"_referencePath":{"segments":[],"projectId":"project-id","databaseId":"(default)"},"_lastSuccessfulRequest":1547738645649,"_validator":{"isFunction":{},"isOptionalFunction":{},"isInteger":{},"isOptionalInteger":{},"isNumber":{},"isOptionalNumber":{},"isObject":{},"isOptionalObject":{},"isString":{},"isOptionalString":{},"isBoolean":{},"isOptionalBoolean":{},"isArrayElement":{},"isOptionalArrayElement":{},"isDeletePrecondition":{},"isOptionalDeletePrecondition":{},"isDocument":{},"isOptionalDocument":{},"isDocumentReference":{},"isOptionalDocumentReference":{},"isFieldPath":{},"isOptionalFieldPath":{},"isFieldValue":{},"isOptionalFieldValue":{},"isFieldOrder":{},"isOptionalFieldOrder":{},"isQueryComparison":{},"isOptionalQueryComparison":{},"isQueryValue":{},"isOptionalQueryValue":{},"isResourcePath":{},"isOptionalResourcePath":{},"isSetOptions":{},"isOptionalSetOptions":{},"isReadOptions":{},"isOptionalReadOptions":{},"isUpdateMap":{},"isOptionalUpdateMap":{},"isUpdatePrecondition":{},"isOptionalUpdatePrecondition":{}},"_preferTransactions":true},"_path":{"segments":["test"],"projectId":"project-id","databaseId":"(default)"},"_fieldFilters":[],"_fieldOrders":[],"_queryOptions":{},"_validator":{"isFunction":{},"isOptionalFunction":{},"isInteger":{},"isOptionalInteger":{},"isNumber":{},"isOptionalNumber":{},"isObject":{},"isOptionalObject":{},"isString":{},"isOptionalString":{},"isBoolean":{},"isOptionalBoolean":{},"isArrayElement":{},"isOptionalArrayElement":{},"isDeletePrecondition":{},"isOptionalDeletePrecondition":{},"isDocument":{},"isOptionalDocument":{},"isDocumentReference":{},"isOptionalDocumentReference":{},"isFieldPath":{},"isOptionalFieldPath":{},"isFieldValue":{},"isOptionalFieldValue":{},"isFieldOrder":{},"isOptionalFieldOrder":{},"isQueryComparison":{},"isOptionalQueryComparison":{},"isQueryValue":{},"isOptionalQueryValue":{},"isResourcePath":{},"isOptionalResourcePath":{},"isSetOptions":{},"isOptionalSetOptions":{},"isReadOptions":{},"isOptionalReadOptions":{},"isUpdateMap":{},"isOptionalUpdateMap":{},"isUpdatePrecondition":{},"isOptionalUpdatePrecondition":{}},"_serializer":{"createReference":{},"timestampsInSnapshots":false}},"_readTime":{"_seconds":1547738645,"_nanoseconds":638303000},"_size":2,"_materializedDocs":null,"_materializedChanges":null,"_docs":{},"_changes":{},"_validator":{"isFunction":{},"isOptionalFunction":{},"isInteger":{},"isOptionalInteger":{},"isNumber":{},"isOptionalNumber":{},"isObject":{},"isOptionalObject":{},"isString":{},"isOptionalString":{},"isBoolean":{},"isOptionalBoolean":{},"isArrayElement":{},"isOptionalArrayElement":{},"isDeletePrecondition":{},"isOptionalDeletePrecondition":{},"isDocument":{},"isOptionalDocument":{},"isDocumentReference":{},"isOptionalDocumentReference":{},"isFieldPath":{},"isOptionalFieldPath":{},"isFieldValue":{},"isOptionalFieldValue":{},"isFieldOrder":{},"isOptionalFieldOrder":{},"isQueryComparison":{},"isOptionalQueryComparison":{},"isQueryValue":{},"isOptionalQueryValue":{},"isResourcePath":{},"isOptionalResourcePath":{},"isSetOptions":{},"isOptionalSetOptions":{},"isReadOptions":{},"isOptionalReadOptions":{},"isUpdateMap":{},"isOptionalUpdateMap":{},"isUpdatePrecondition":{},"isOptionalUpdatePrecondition":{}}}}
```

At first I thought it might be an issue with serialization, but if I modify my cloud function to return just a single `DocumentSnapshot`, that returns with the expected data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a problem with serialization.  You're trying to return a complex object that wasn't meant to be serialized directly.  Instead, you should iterate the documents in the query snapshot, build whatever object you want to return (an array?) and return that.  Something like this:

```
const querySnapshot = await db.collection('test').get();
return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick & thorough response. I will use that approach. However, is what I'm trying to do a scenario that is planned for future support?  My larger goal was to be able to enforce some business rules in the cloud function then construct and return a `QuerySnapshot` on the client's behalf that it could use directly.  (I know I could conceivably return the relevant data then construct the `QuerySnapshot` on the client, but I was attempting to avoid multiple client implementations of this.)

Comment: I think you will always have to customize the response to the client in the server.  It should always be a plain JSON object.

Comment: @DougStevenson This seems to be true also for "Timestamp" which is not received by the client properly when sending a custom object built function-side. It is neither a proper Timestamp nor can you read `seconds` or `nanoseconds` from it, although there { _nanoseconds: "...", _seconds: "..." }. How do I need to deal with that object properly? Can I transform it to a proper Timestamp client-side?

Comment: @AlexeiS. There are a lot of questions on stack overflow that discuss the serialization of Timestamp type objects.

Comment: I'm getting "Data cannot be encoded in JSON" as error message. What might be the problem?